# How do you get dialog popup on phonegap + jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

Through searches/documentation I read all you have to do is use data-rel="dialog" on the call to any page and it should open the page as a dialog box. I am building a store submittable app (not web app) using phone gap + jquery mobile for Android.

Tapping on below anchor opens the page as a regular page not a dialog. What am I doing wrong or not doing?

```
     <a href="use_coins.html" data-rel="dialog">Open dialog Box</a>
```

Here is the src for use_coins.html

```
<div data-role="page" class="my-bg" id="use_coins_dialog">


    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Show coins here</p>

    </div><!-- /content -->

    </div><!-- /page -->


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference all this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

in the  page containing

```
<a href="use_coins.html" data-rel="dialog">Open dialog Box</a>
```

Comment: That page already has everything indeed in terms of including these js and css files

Comment: ok so provide more source to debug it ! because it works like a charm in my prototype for your case...there is certainly a mistake somewhere in your page that we cannot see in the code you provided

Comment: that page has these as well 
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" />

Comment: We don't have access to your index.css that could overwrite jquery.mobile.css. Please provide real and full source ! or, at least, take the time to reduce your code to point us your problem. As i said, actually there is no pb with the code you provided and JQuery Mobile, so you have a bug somewhere in your page that we cannot see

Comment: removed index.css which was generated by phonegap but seeing no difference. The page loads fine but is just not a dialog.

Comment: The problem is in a part of your code that you have not provided

Comment: Dear user2196728. If I could isolate the problematic code by giving you a minimalistic code I'd very likely not have to ask for any help. Thanks for your continued attempts but I am okay living with the problem.